# Debugging keypresses in Vim

Tags: vim, plugins

For some reason my Vim has gotten pretty slow when I try to switch from Insert mode to Normal mode - sometimes I have to wait 2 seconds to make a switch, sometimes I have to press  twice. It may be related to plugins (I have many of them installed at the moment) or to my own mappings.

How can I debug keypresses in Vim (for example, print to the log what actually happens when I press a certain key)?

Comment: You could run vim in verbose mode: vim -v2 or in debug mode vim -D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can capture a full log of a Vim session with `vim -V20vimlog`. After quitting Vim, examine the `vimlog` log file for suspect commands.

However, for this timing issue, there's probably an easier approach: The delay can only be caused by either a mapping on the `<Esc>` key (especially in the terminal you have to deal with the ambiguity with escape codes, which also start with Escape), or by code run on `InsertLeave`. So, check whether something's mapped:

```
:verbose imap <Esc>
```

and list (and then disable one by one) the autocmds:

```
:verbose autocmd InsertLeave
```

Comment: Thanks - as always, your advice is invaluable.

Comment: BTW, if I have multiple `InsertLeave` (or any other) autcommands, should I group them in one place in my `.vimrc` or can I have them in separate places and it won't have significant impact on Vim's performace?

Comment: The real overhead is in the commands being executed; I don't think it matters how _many_ `:autocmd` definitions there are. So group them logically by functionality.